# How to retrieve the values from two tables in form load event

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I am developing windows application in which i have bounded datagridview and textboxes controls. I want to retrieve the values from two different tables on from load event.

That means datagridview values stored in one table and textbox values stored in other table. How could I do?

Here is my `form_load` event code:

```
private void Purchase_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   bindgrid();
}

private void bindgrid()
{
   try
   {
       con.Open();
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct product_id, product_name, qty, price, tax, discount, total from Purchasedetail union all select total from Purchase ", con);
       da.SelectCommand = cmd;
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       da.Fill(ds, "Purchsedetail");
       da.Fill(ds, "Purchase");

       datagrid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Exception caught : " + ex.Message.ToString());
   }
   finally
   {
      con.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: You called bindgrdi() and function name is bindgrid()

Comment: You are writing a wrong query. Can you explain what values should go in the grid and what values should go in the textboxe(s). ?

Comment: first select query should retrieve data in gridview and second query retreive data in only one textbox called total.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the two select commands with a semicolon. (UNION tries to merge the two resultsets in a single resultset and need to have two resultsets with identical schema)

```
try
{
    con.Open();
    string cmdText = @"select distinct product_id, product_name, 
                             qty, price, tax, discount, total 
                             from Purchasedetail;
                       select total from Purchase ";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con); 

    // You pass the command and fill the DataSet. 
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    // Now the Dataset contains two tables
    datagrid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

    // Of course this retrieves just the total from the first row,
    // I suppose that your second query needs some kind of WHERE condition
    // or some kind of aggregate function like SUM(Total) 
    textBox1.Text = ds.Tables[1].Rows[0][0].ToString();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Exception caught : " + ex.Message);
} 
finally
{
   con.Close();
}
```

Comment: its working but textbox value is not getting a new value on different total value after saving total value.if i insert a datagridview cell value then total will automatically calculated in textbox,but that calculated value not retrieving at form loading time

Comment: I have said that in comments above. You need to add a WHERE clause to search for the record corresponding to the Purchase that you want to show the total for. As is, the second query finds all the Total fields of your table records. In the TextBox you can show just one record at a time. You need a `WHERE IDPurchase = ?` (some ID from your purchase table, but I am guessing here) and this is outside the scope of this question. I suggest to add another question (and take the habit to accept the useful answers given to you otherwise you will have difficult times to find new answers) See HELP